# How to reject IdP-initiated SSO authentication with Spring Security SAML?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, saml

I am using Spring Security SAML in a Grails application to implement IdP-initiated SSO. And when the user whose username I receive in the `SAMLResponse` does not exist in my database, I don't want to create a new one, and I don't want to populate `UserDetails` with data from assertion. I just want authentication to fail. Which is why I throw a `UsernameNotFoundException` from my implementation of `SAMLUserDetailsService.loadUserBySAML()`. Unfortunately it doesn't work as it seems to redirect me back to my IdP, which in turn starts the authentication process again, and I end up in an infinite redirection loop.

Is there any other thing to do to make my IdP (Azure Active Directory) show an error message in that case?